# Is there an Average Operator?

Tags: math-operators

In the same way that `\min` and `\max` work, is there a version for "ave" meaning the average?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! DO you look for command `\ave`? This is not standard way to write average (mostly people use line over expression). However, you can define it as `\DeclareMathOperator{\ave}{ave}`. For this you need to load `amsmath` package in document preamble: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ave}{ave}

\begin{document}
$\ave{X}$
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko - Please make your comment into a standalone answer.

Comment: @Mico, done. Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me spell-out my comment to an answer:

- `ave` is not standard way to write average (mostly people use line over expression).
- however, you can define it as `DeclareMathOperator{\ave}{ave}` (for this you need to load `amsmath` package in document preamble):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\ave}{ave} 

\begin{document} 
$\ave{X(t)}$ (\verb+\ave{X(t)}+) or $\ave X(t)$ (\verb+\ave X(t)+) but people usually write $\overline{X(t)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sadly I do need "ave" and not just the bar!